# Alternative to Redirecting command input in windows

Tags: windows, input, batch-file, command, redirect

Is there any way I coluld use some alternative approch to "redirecting command input" in windows command shell? For example, consider the following command:

app.exe < ListOfNames.txt

Content of the file ListOfNames.txt might be:
Name1
Name2
Name3

So, is it possible to avoid using redircting operator and use something like this:

app.exe Name1 Name2 Name3

Of course, this wouldn't work, but is there some similar approach that could work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to win a [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) by using [type](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/type.php) on Windows:

```
type ListOfNames.txt | app.exe
```

Comment: Yes this works in command shell, but I must avoid pipe as well.

Comment: If your app reads from stdin, there are no more alternatives. You can write a command which feeds your app: `feed.exe app.exe Name1 Name2 Name3`. But this would be a pipe either.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to change app.exe to receive list of names as parameters.